# How can learn to controll beaglebone black with ros? Any books, links, tutorials or anything?

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing a project where i want to controll sensors and motors connted to beglebone black with ros nodes. How can i learn to do that? Any book, video link, online course or anything which i can use? Till now i'be finished the ros.wiki tutorial and learned how to make packags, nodes, but still don't know the format of writing ros c++ codes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234575/how-can-learn-to-controll-beaglebone-black-with-ros?-any-books,-links,-tutorials-or-anything?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can forget about a book and all that. My advice is to start from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/BeagleBone) and move on by simply googling for general projects with ROS that handle 3D object recognition. If I'm not mistaken there is actually a Ubuntu-port for the BeagleBone. Also BeagleBone (as far as I know) has an ARM processor so things should be close to a development environment such as the Raspberry Pi. The low level stuff in BeagleBone (like accessing the GPIOs) is not ROS related and you should look for some tutorials on that somewhere else. Basically you have to:

- Learn how BeagleBone works
- Get your hands on a Linux distribution which runs on BeagleBone (Debian-based is probably the simplest way since ROS is officially supported only on Ubuntu systems)
- Build from source (if no pre-build of ROS is available for BeagleBone - again check the link I've posted above)
- Once you've setup your ROS environment the rest is basically checking some ROS tutorials on the topic of 3D object recognition combined with some BeagleBone-specific code (for example blink an LED if an object has been recognized etc.).

---

Originally posted by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) with karma: 299 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1